# Database settings in persistence.xml not used

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I'm new to JPA, and to try to teach myself, I'm setting up a tiny web application and deploying to Glassfish 3.1.

JPA works fine when I refer to a JNDI DataSource in persistence.xml, such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="foo" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/foo</jta-data-source>
        <class>my.app.Foo</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But as far as I understand, it is supposed to be possible to put all my database connection settings into properties in persistence.xml. This may not be good practice, but it seems like it could be handy when I'm just experimenting, and perhaps during unit testing.

However, when I follow the examples I have found for this, persistence.xml seems to be just ignored and instead the default container-managed DataSource, jndi/__default is used. This is a Derby instance that is not running.

I've tried this file for an ephemeral in-memory Derby instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="foo" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>my.app.Foo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:NxtMv;create=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have also tried this for a PostgreSQL server (which works when accessed through JNDI):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="foo" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>my.app.Foo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myuser"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="secret"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

There's probably some irrelevant cruft in those files which has accumulated during my countless tries and retries.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use manually configured datasource with `transaction-type="JTA"`.

JPA Spec says:

> A transaction-type of JTA
>   assumes that a JTA data source will be provided—either as specified by the jta-data-source element
>   or provided by the container.

Try to use `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` instead (though I'm not sure how would it work with container-managed transactions, if you use them).

Comment: I've tried this, but you are right; this gives the error "Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager." when I try to deploy. What is a scenario in which I can use RESOURCE_LOCAL and still deploy?

Comment: @Coder: As far as I understand you can't use contrainer-managed transactions without JTA datasource. That is, using manually configured datasource requires you to manage transactions manually (on a persistence context obtained via `Persistence.createEntitiyManagerFactory()`). It looks like one more inflexibility of EJB.

Comment: @Coder Doe: You have no choice but to use JTA data source if you're using container-managed transactions. I don't think this will change any time soon! Servers which support JTA directly are: Glassfish, JBoss, Websphere. Non-JTA servers: Tomcat.